# Running function over but with different parameters

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi this is probably very simple but I am new to R and would really appreciate some help. Basically I have this command:

`length(days_to_death[which(days_to_death<100)])`

I would like to make a list of each of the results when each time its run I add 100 to the <100 up until it is <1000. Basically I would like to simplify this:

`c(length(days_to_death[which(days_to_death<100)]),length(days_to_death[which(days_to_death<200)])...<1000)`

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Your question has already been answered, but your example looks like you're attaching data. This can lead to a lot of issues later on, so use indexes (`mydata$days_to_death`) or `with(mydata, length(days_to_death[which(days_to_death<100)])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an `sapply` to loop over these values and `seq` to create that list of values. Then we can simplify your length call as well, since it is actually just a sum.

```
sapply(seq(100,1000,by=100), function(i) sum(days_to_death < i))
```